# jQuery Click(): Change arguments of a function after it has been executed

Tags: jquery, function, arguments

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
function z(a,b,c){
    $("#d").click(function(){
        var sum = a+b+c;
        x(sum)
    }

    function x(first){
        var second = first*(first+1);
        var third = second*(second+1);
        $("#e").animate({
            "left": "+=first%"
        },{
            complete:function(){
                z(first, second, third)
        });
```

**I want the first function [`function z`] to be triggered with different arguments and "unbind" its previous `.click() event` after the animation.**

---

*So that the first time click on `#d`, `#e` moves `(a+b+c)%`. 
The second time click on `#d`, `#e` moves `(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)*(a+b+c+1)+(a+b+c)*(a+b+c+1)*((a+b+c)*(a+b+c+1)+1)%`. The third time ...*

I've tried using `unbind` but it didn't seem to be fit into this situation. I ended up writing more and more messy codes. I don't think using `unbind` is a smart way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function z(a,b,c){
        x(a+b+c);
}

function x(first) {
    var second = first*(first+1);
    var third = second*(second+1);
    $("#e").animate({
    "left": "+=first%"
    },{
    complete:function(){
    z(first, second, third)
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#d").one("click",function(){
        z(1,2,3);
    });
});
```

the "one()" function will ensure that your "click" event is unbound after you click it the first time.

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/one/